# not able to set the other variables inside dirReader.readEntries() html5

Tags: html5-filesystem

I am working on folder uploads in HTML5. I am using the DirectoryReader.readEntries function() to read the entries inside the directory. I am successfully able to iterate over the entries but I need to return the list of names of all the names of the entries inside the directory. I tried creating an array outside and setting it inside the readEntries function, but it array is set inside the function properly and is unchanged outside the readEntries function. I also tried using a global variable and set the values there, but that too doesn't seem to work. Also, in some cases I have seen on the web that we can do 
var entries  = dirReader.readEntries(); and it does return the entries and then we can iterate over it. But in my case it throws an exception and is not able to read the directory.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryReaderSync

My code :

```
var subResourceNames = [];
 var dirReader = e.createReader();
 dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
     for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        subResourceNames.push(new String(entry.name));
        }
 });

console.log("outside readEntries (subresourcenames ):"+subResourceNames);
return subResourceNames;
```

subResourceNames is still empty when it comes outside the readEntries, but if I print it after the for loop is complete it is giving a populated array.What should I do to the the values outside. Even returning the value from the readEntries function and assigning it to some variable doesn't work.

Comment: I think the problem is that the success callback of the readEntries function is asynchronous and the function does not run sequentially with the enclosing function. Also my console.log gets printed before the control goes inside the readEntries. It has to do with the async nature of the callback. Moreover I could not find much resource of using the Synchronous DirectoryReaderSync interface. Any help on the way to implement this interface will also be appreciated.